# Using data attributes with jquery.confirm.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to utilise the [jquery.confirm](https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/) script. It's all firing as expected but I'm trying to use custom `data` attributes that are passed into a controller elsewhere on the site, but I'm getting the error of `undefined`.

```
<a class="confirmMemberDelete" data-title="Mr Goose" data-user="CON-000132456" data-username="Mr Goose" href="#">
```

```js
$(".confirmMemberDelete").confirm({
    text: "Are you sure that you wish to delete this user?",
    confirm: function (button) {
        var conNum = $(this).attr('data-user');
        var conName = $(this).attr('data-username');
        alert("You just confirmed.");
        alert($(this).attr('data-user'));
    },
    cancel: function (button) {
        alert("You aborted the operation.");
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes I am",
    cancelButton: "No"
});
```

The two custom `data` attributes are `data-user` and `data-username`. `data-title` is used by the confirm script as a title for the confirmation box.

I can't find any documentation online so any help would be marvellous.

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: The plugin seems to have a bug. What the documentation says is the 'button' being passed in to the `confirm` event handler is actually the whole popup - you can tell as the border is added to that element in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3qf6w6zq/. I would put a note on the github page for the plugin that this should be fixed.

Comment: Ah bugger, thanks for looking though my friend

Answer (score 1):

Still not fixed in version 3.3.4, but I'm able to extract the data attributes the following way.

```
<a class="confirmMemberDelete" data-title="Mr Goose" data-user="CON-000132456" data-username="Mr Goose" href="#">

$('.confirmMemberDelete').confirm({
    title: 'Make this my profile picture',
    buttons: {
        ok: function () {
            let user = $(this)[0].$target[0].dataset.user;              
            let username = $(this)[0].$target[0].dataset.username;              
            console.log(user, username);

        },
        cancel: function () {

        }
    }
});
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbLk8qc9/)